# How to deal with CSS, JS files when used with global apache redirect (for user friendly url's)

Tags: php, apache, url, redirect

I have the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

From rewrite.php I redirect to the correct pages depending on the url. Problem is that it redirects all files including css and js. I tried including these files but I now realise that was dumb of me. Should I redirect when there is and appropriate extension in the url? If redirecting is the way to go what method would be best? header location or HTTP_redirect?

Or is this not a good idea performance or work involved wise? I could go for something like this but I know next to nothing about apache and would rather not work with it right now.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /includes/compressor.php?i=$1.css [L]
```

I previously had the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

I decided to remove this because:

1. I would not be able to include the header and other common files in the rewrite.php file. I would also not be able to have a database call in the rewrite file that would determine the page to include and to reuse the data for the page contents.
2. Unwanted files would be reachable such as service used only by external app.

Comment: I wonder how wordpress achieves it (it redirects everything to index.php)... I could not decipher it from looking at the files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about redirecting only if the requested file does not exist on the server?

You could use the following rewrite conditions to achieve this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So if the request is for a CSS/JS/HTML/Image file that already exists on the server then no rewriting takes place and the request for the file is processed.  If the file does not exist, it will run your rewrite rule to rewrite.php

Comment: I'm unclear on reason #1 and isn't the case for #2 the same with or without that?

Comment: Yes, I guess it was more of a convenience to have the header/footer includes in rewrite.php as opposed to all the other file that I have. I still think there's a reason but I can't think of a good one right now, surely wordpress designers had a pretty good reason, can you think of any?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "-l" and "RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]" ? I wan't able to determine it from rewrite cheatsheet :)

Comment: The `-l` just says if %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is a valid symlink that points to a file.  And the `RewriteRule ^.$ -` is the way you say to not rewrite the request.  `^.*$` matches everything and the `-` is basically not rewriting the request, it just says to Apache to serve the file as it was requested.

Answer (score 2):

The compression should be done once, and not for every request. You can then exclude requests from the URL rewriting if the corresponding file exists:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @DominicM What you should do anyway is move all files that are not supposed to be delivered by apache as they are out of the public directory. Everything that is in "htdocs" (or whatever it is called on your server) should be destined to be directly delivered.